# Node - CSV is not working

Tags: node.js, express, export-to-csv

I am using nodejs v0.10.26 and expressjs.

I want to implement data export in CSV format functionality in application and for this i am using node-csv 0.3.7

**JS**

```
var csv = require('csv');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Report.csv');
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/csv'});
csv().from(callBack).to(res);
```

But it is not prompting any CSV file, i am getting just text data in service response.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code? I want CSV file prompt in this scenario.

**Updates**

Here callBack = JSON object which contains data

res = response

Comment: What is `callBack`?  What is `res`?  Not much to work with here.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Here callBack = JSON object which contains data
 and res = response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var csv = require('csv');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Report.csv');
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/csv'});

csv.parse(callBack, function(err, output) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    res.write(output);
});
```

I tested the `csv.parse` function with this code:

```
var parse = require('csv-parse');

var data = '"1","2","3","4"\n"a","b","c","d"';


parse(data, function(err, output) {
        if(err){
                throw err;
        }

        console.log(output);
});
```

Also, as a side note, I'd recommend not calling a data-containing variable `callBack`, as convention tends to name callback functions `callback`. It will work your way, but it will confuse anyone reading your code.